# How can i increment month name in trigger?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[trg_Billing_TotalFee] on [dbo].[tblBilling] after insert as insert into tblTotalFee(DueFromPreviousMonth,StudentID,MonthName) select RemainingAmount,StudentID,MonthName from inserted
```

This is my trigger. What I want is in place of **MonthName** i want **MonthName++** in **tbltotalfee** i.e. Let's say MonthName in tblBilling is **January** then in **tblTotalFee** i want month to be inserted as **Febraury**.How can i do this??

Comment: Do you have somewhere a list of Month Names? In some table? Like a dictionary? Can you change the structure of your tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Create a table called `nextMonths` with 2 columns - `currentMonthName` and `nextMonthName`. Populate the table with currentMonth and corresponding nextMonth name for each.

Now your trigger should be :

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[trg_Billing_TotalFee] 
on [dbo].[tblBilling] after insert as 
insert into tblTotalFee(DueFromPreviousMonth,StudentID,MonthName) 
select RemainingAmount,StudentID,NextMonthName from inserted join nextMonths on inserted.MonthName = nextMonths.currentMonthName
```